# Python login different accounts through a loop

Tags: python, selenium

I want to loop through multiple account after closing one account and i want to give the password and username from excel file

```py
username = '********'
password = '********'
URL = 'HTTP://Facebook/'
driver = web driver. Chrome("/web-drivers/chrome-driver")
driver.get(URL)
driver.find_element_by_id('email').send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_id('pass').send_keys(password)
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_id('login-button').click()
time.sleep(10)
driver.close()
```

Comment: how do you read csv file? using `csv` module or `pandas`?

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly?

Comment: @Sociopath I am using csv module

Comment: @DebanjanB on Excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a list of emails and passwords

```
list_of_mails = ["ex@ex.com","ax@ax.com"]
list_of_passwords = ["abc1234","axpassword"]
```

put them in order in the list

```
for a,b in list_of_mails,list_of_passwords:
   a = username
   b = password
```

and then run the rest of your code in the for loop.

make sure to change ip addresses when you do this. Facebook might block the selenium driver.

or at least put a time.sleep in

Answer (score 0):

If you want to login directly form account you have to use libraries like xlrd or openyxl to read from your excel file and import your users from your excel file then you can directly use those user values to login into your account.